# Get and display event id for Google Calender api (Python)

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am using the basic quickstart program to test code before adding it to my work project, and I am having trouble with how to retrieve the event ids and display them. Once I manage this step, I'm going to store them and use the ids to delete events.

Here is my errror:

> event = service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId').execute()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
>   googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/eventId?alt=json returned "Not Found">

The code that's generating it is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])
    event = service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId').execute()

    print(event['summary'])

    #service.events().delete(calendarId='primary', eventId='4qvgpuca08lp3rki5vnuo7qp7r').execute()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm still very new, so I am sure it's a foolish mistake. I tried wrapping eventID in the service.events().list section, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the String `eventId` where you should have an actual event Id. So you could change your code here from this:

```
    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])
    event = service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId').execute()

    print(event['summary'])

    #service.events().delete(calendarId='primary', eventId='4qvgpuca08lp3rki5vnuo7qp7r').execute()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To this:

```
    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])
        service.events().delete(calendarId='primary', eventId=event['id']).execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way you are already deleting the events after listing them. Notice the syntax for `eventId=event['id']`. The `id` is a property of the Event object. You can see the rest of the properties [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events).